Downloadable Conversations While I Cannot Be Online
Saluton!
Are there any downloadable audio files so I can practice listening when I cannot get online?
Donkon,
Michael

Even if a little bit old take a look at the books Jen nia mondo 1 and Jen nia mondo 2 which are downloadable with recordings at Espeanto-Asocio de Britio (requires registration).

Kvankam ne nepre temas pri dialogoj, alia rimedo por trejni aŭskultadon estas sonlibro. Ĉe Librivox oni trovas kelkajn en la esperanta.
